# Validating JWT Token in vue.js Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, jwt, vue-router

I am using the following code to generate a JWT token:

```
 jwt.sign(id, TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '24h' });
```

Once generated, I send the token to the client, which stores it within a cookie:

```
 document.cookie = `session=${token}` + ';' + expires + ';path=/'
```

Furthermore, I am using vue.js Router for my navigation. From my understanding, if one adds the following code in the router file, one can insert middle-ware in order to protect some routes.

```
 router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
   let token = Vue.cookie.get('session')
   if (token == null) {
     next({
      path: '/',
      params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
    })
  }
 } else {
  next()
 }
})
```

However, I am having difficulty understanding how can one verify the validity of the JWT token using this approach, which needs to be done on the server, where the TOKEN_SECRET is stored, and not on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with this: your goal in guarding routes is to prevent the user from having a bad experience by proceeding to a page that will attempt to retrieve information that they are not authorized to view.

So, you don't need to validate the token on the client side.  Since a token will only be in hand if the server validated the user and returned a token, you - the author of the client code - can use the presence of the token as a means to inform what route to take the user through.

**In other words, the client having a token is all the validation you need to allow the user through to protected routes.**

Remember, it is not as though a protected page has private data in and of itself.  A protected page will always retrieve that protected data from the server, which means that the server has the chance to authenticate the token after all.

Comment: Put it this way: what is your concern when it comes to protecting a route?  You really are only trying to direct the user to a login form if necessary.  What you're trying to avoid is letting the user through to a page that will not be useful because it requires a protected API call when the user has not authenticated.  Why wouldn't having the token in hand be enough for you to at least allow the user through to the next step?

Comment: OK, I took one last shot at clarifying.  I hope there is some value here.

Comment: The router is designed to rerender the client rather than make a server request.  That said, you can watch for a route change in a number of ways and upon trapping certain changes invoke an API call to query the server.

Comment: Thank you very much crosen9999 for your time, help and explanations. I finally understood your answer and how the Router works!